# Limitations to storing profile data retrieved from LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

Is it allowed to store a profile's company name as provided by LinkedIn Profile API?

The [Terms of Use](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use) refer to certain limitations when it comes to storing retrieved data and it's not clear to me whether this particular datum is allowed or not.

First, when they refer to *Profile Data* that can be stored only a few fields are mentioned (name, photo, headline, contact information, experience, education, summary, and location); is that meant to be a comprehensive list?

And second, they explicitly exclude *companies* but I'm not sure whether they refer to data provided by the *Profile API* (*positions* in *Basic Profile Fields*) or data retrieved from the *Profile Company API*.

Any advice?

### References to the [Terms of Use](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use)

> #### Introduction / Scope and Intent / Self-Service Program
>
> You cannot use our self-service program [...],  if your Application [...] will store or export any data from LinkedIn other than a LinkedIn member’s profile data (name, photo, headline, contact information, experience, education, summary, and location). [...]

And:

> #### Act Professionally / Store Content Only As Allowed / Member Profile Data
>
> You may store a user’s Profile Data if you have the consent of the user to do so [...]. “Profile Data” means the name, photo, headline, contact information, experience, education, summary, and location of a LinkedIn member. Profile Data excludes connections, network updates, job listings, groups, companies, and any other Content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've referenced from the [Terms of Use](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use), member profile data contains the following pieces of information:

- Name
- Photo
- Headline
- Contact Information
- **Experience**
- Education
- Summary
- Location

And it excludes:

- Connections
- Network Updates
- Job Listings
- Groups
- **Companies**
- Other Content

Looking at these lists, we can take `Experience` as it's used on LinkedIn to refer to the role held by the user at a company, and so you would naturally have access to the name of the company.

The [Platform Guidelines](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-platform-guidelines), point `3.2`:

> [..] You may only store the profile of that person, not the profile data of that person's connections, network updates, or other network information.

Looking at the API documentation for [Profile Fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields), in the sub-sections referring to `Positions` and `Company`, you can see that:

> Positions are structured objects returned as part of profile.

Including the following fields:

- Job title
- Summary
- **Company**

> Company is a structured object returned as part of profile.
>
> Not used directly with people calls, but used in position calls.

Including the following fields:

- **Company name**
- Company industry

So you should be fine to use this information.